# Python: Generate a unique batch from given dataset

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, classification, generator

I'm applying a CNN to classify a given dataset.

My function:

```
def batch_generator(dataset, input_shape = (256, 256), batch_size = 32):
    dataset_images = []
    dataset_labels = []
    for i in range(0, len(dataset)):
        dataset_images.append(cv2.resize(cv2.imread(dataset[i], cv2.IMREAD_COLOR), 
                     input_shape, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA))
        dataset_labels.append(labels[dataset[i].split('/')[-2]])
    return dataset_images, dataset_labels
```

This function is supposed to be called for every epoch and it should return a unique batch of size 'batch_size' containing dataset_images (each image is 256x256) and corresponding dataset_label from the labels dictionary.

input 'dataset' contains path to all the images, so I'm opening them and resizing them to 256x256. Can someone help me in adding to this code so that is returns the desired batches?

Comment: Can you clarify how you expect to use this function and what you mean by "unique batch"? Do you mean each element should be unique within the batch? Or that you want to randomly partition the dataset into batches of size 32 and iterate over all of those? In either case it seems more appropriate to use a [`torch.utils.data.DataLoader`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html) rather than writing your own generator.

Comment: @jodag I want to randomly partition the dataset into batches of size 32. These will be passed to my CNN model for training for specific epochs. Hope it clear things up.

Comment: I checked DataLoader class. It seems it takes input dataset. However I have separate list for dataset containing 256x256 images and a separate list of labels for those images. Can you elaborate how I can combine them and pass to DataLoader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyTorch has two similar sounding, but very different abstractions for loading data. I strongly recommend reading the documentation on dataloaders [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html). To summarize

1. A Data**set** is an object you generally implement that returns an individual sample (data + label)
2. A Data**Loader** is a built-in class in pytorch that samples batches of samples from a dataset (potentially in parallel).

A (map-style) Dataset is a simple object that just implements two mandatory methods: `__getitem__` and `__len__`. Getitem is the method that is invoked on an object when you use the square-bracket operator i.e. `dataset[i]` and `__len__` is the method that is invoked when you use the python built-in `len` function on your object, i.e. `len(dataset)`

For pytorch you usually want `__getitem__` to return a tuple containing both the data and the label for a single item in your dataset object. For example based on what you provided, something like this should suit your needs

```py
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
import torchvision.transforms.functional as F

class CustomDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, image_paths, labels, input_shape=(256, 256)):
        # `image_paths` is what you called `dataset` in your example.
        #               I'm assume this is a list of image paths.
        # `labels` isn't defined in your script but I assume its a
        #          dict that maps image names to an integer label
        #          between 0 and num classes minus 1
        self.image_paths = image_paths
        self.labels = labels
        self.input_shape = input_shape

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        # return the data and label for the specified index
        image_path = self.image_paths[index]
        data = cv2.resize(cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR), 
                          self.input_shape, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
        label = self.labels[image_path.split('/')[-2]]

        # convert data to PyTorch tensor
        # This converts data from a uint8 np.array of shape HxWxC
        # between 0 and 255 to a pytorch float32 tensor of shape CxHxW
        # between 0.0 and 1.0.
        data = F.to_tensor(data)

        return data, label

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.image_paths)

...
# using what you call "dataset" and "labels"
# num_workers > 0 allows you to load data in parallel while network is running
dataloader = DataLoader(
    CustomDataset(dataset, labels, (256, 256)),
    batch_size=32,
    shuffle=True,    # shuffle tells us to randomly sample the
                     # dataset without replacement
    num_workers=4    # num workers is the number of worker processes
                     # that load from dataset in parallel while your
                     # model is processing stuff
)

# training loop
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    # iterates over all data in your dataset in a random order
    # in batches of size 32 each time this loop is run
    for data_batch, label_batch in dataloader:
        # data_batch is a pytorch FloatTensor of shape 32x3x256x256
        # label_batch is a pytorch LongTensor of shape 32

        # if using GPU acceleration now is the time to move data_batch and label_batch to GPU
        # data_batch = data_batch.cuda()
        # label_batch = label_batch.cuda()

        # zero the gradients, pass data through your model, backprop, and step the optimizer
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much for providing a detailed response. It cleared my ambiguities to a great extent. Just had one minor problem now, if I run with num_worker set to any non-zero values I get an error that pid x, y, z closed unexpectedly. Running it with 0 however iterated through the model without any error. Can you provide any insight?

Comment: @Ashar Possibly an issue with whatever system you're running on not allowing forking of processes. Or perhaps there's no space available in the place where torch wants to share information (`/dev/shm` on linux, not sure on windows). Worst case is just that you will need to use 0 workers which is slower than using > 0 workers. Also, if this provides a useful answer please consider accepting and/or upvoting.

Comment: I'm running it on macOS Monterey 12.0.1. Maybe that's the issue here. Anyways it solves the larger problem I had. Accepted this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As @jodag suggests, using DataLoaders is a good idea.

I have a snippet of that I use for some of my CNN in Pytorch

```py
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
import torch
class Data(Dataset):
    """
    Constructs a Dataset to be parsed into a DataLoader
    """
    def __init__(self,X,y):
        X = torch.from_numpy(X).float()

        #Transpose to fit dimensions of my network
        X = torch.transpose(X,1,2)

        y = torch.from_numpy(y).float()
        self.X,self.y = X,y

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return self.X[i],self.y[i]

    def __len__(self):
        return self.X.shape[0]

def create_data_loader(X,y,batch_size,**kwargs):
    """
    Creates a data-loader for the data X and y

    params:
    -------

    X: np.array
        - numpy array of size "n" x k where n is samples an "k" is number of features

    y: np.array
        - numpy array of sie "n"

    batch_size: int
        - Take a wild guess, dumbass

    kwargs:
        - Additional keyword-arguments for "DataLoader"

    return
    ------

    dl: torch.utils.data.DataLoader object
    """

    data = Data(X, y)

    dl = DataLoader(data, batch_size=batch_size,num_workers=0,**kwargs)
    return dl
```

which is used like this;

```py
from create_data_loader import create_data_loader

train_data_loader= create_data_loader(X_train,y_train,batch_size=32) #Note, it has "shuffle=True" as default!
val_data_loader= create_data_loader(X_val,y_val,batch_size=32,shuffle=False) #If you want to keep index'es in the same order for e.g cross-validate


for x_train, y_train in train_data_loader:
   logit = net(x_train,y_train)
   .
   .
   net.eval()
   for x_val,y_val in val_data_loader:
       logit  = net(x_val,y_val)
       classes_pred = logit.argmax(axis=1)
       print(f"Val accuracy: {(y_val==classes_pred).mean()}")
```